# Realizing SQL substatements in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a Database where every Order has a reference to a Customer which has a reference to a User. Every Order has one Customer and every Customer has one User. Now I would like to access all the Orders that are belonging to a User. In SQL I would write:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT id from customers WHERE user_id = 1)
```

How can I access them in Laravel without using SQL.
Thank You!

Comment: Have you looked into [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) and [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships)?

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 2):

```
DB::table('orders')
->whereIn('customer_id', function($query)
{
    $query->select('id')
          ->from('customers')
          ->where('user_id', 1);
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

implement this way:
in your **user** model implement **customer** relationship like this:

```
public function customer {
   $this->belongsTo(Customer::class)->with('order'); // calling order relationship from customer model
 }
```

then in your **customer** model implement relationship with **order** model like this:

```
public function order {
 $this->belongsTo(Order::class); 
}
```

then you implement a query like this:

```
 User::with('customer')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As aynber points out, you should use [models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) and [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

```
class Order extends Model {}

class Customer extends Model {}

class User extends Model {
    public function orders() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Customer::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can get a user's order like this:

```
$orders = User::find(1)->orders;
```